# Zero flow files in onTrigger() method of AbstractProcessor of Apache Nifi

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am developing a custom processor for Apache NiFi. I have created nar of my processor and put it in the lib folder of nifi and started the nifi. I have setup the remote debugger in eclipse and enabled breakpoint on first line of `onTrigger()`. While debugging I am running one processor at a time in my nifi pipeline. I can find single flow file in the input queue of my custom processor, however my custom processor is not receiving any flow file. When I start my custom processor, it hits breakpoint inside `onTrigger()` method. Inside thie method, when I do:

```
public class MyCustomProc extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {

        List<FlowFile> flowFiles = session.get(5000);
        if (flowFiles == null || flowFiles.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        //...
```

`flowFiles` turns out to be of size zero!!! ***I am not able to guess in which direction should I check to find why this is happening. Any hint how I can diagnose this?***

**Edit**

Stacktrace

```
2019-05-02 18:08:09,456 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] c.c.product.module.submodule.MyCustomProcessor MyCustomProcessor[id=016a1008-8956-1dbf-bd66-993e0ce98668] MyCustomProcessor[id=016a1008-8956-1dbf-bd66-993e0ce98668] failed to process due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=408fbb3d-7cc2-48bc-be8f-6d0afdbddaf2,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1556800468726-1, container=default, section=1], offset=261, length=591447],offset=0,name=188149730353200,size=591447] transfer relationship not specified; rolling back session: {}
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=408fbb3d-7cc2-48bc-be8f-6d0afdbddaf2,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1556800468726-1, container=default, section=1], offset=261, length=591447],offset=0,name=188149730353200,size=591447] transfer relationship not specified
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.checkpoint(StandardProcessSession.java:251)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.commit(StandardProcessSession.java:321)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:28)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1122)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**PS1:** This method returns immediately from inside `if`'s body, which gives me following exception:

`org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord transfer relationship not specified`

This exceptions keeps recurring forever, since flow file in the input queue of my custom processor.

**PS2:** I am getting following error in the apps.log, though I am unsure if this is the source of the problem:

```
2019-05-02 18:17:32,394 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4] o.a.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroup Unable to synchronize StandardProcessGroup[identifier=d25747e6-719e-3ed9-c6c5-56794af6555c] with Flow Registry because Process Group was placed under Version Control using Flow Registry with identifier 80016ab0-bfab-152b-ffff-ffffc441867c but cannot find any Flow Registry with this identifier
```

Comment: The source of the problem is code ) please provide the code especially all about session, and error with stacktrace.

Comment: Yeah...I completely forgot to add stacktrace. Added now. As you can see, it is barely executing my custom processor specific code.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal behavior to sometimes get zero flow files, which is why processors have the check that you have at the beginning.

The FlowFileHandlingException means that a flow file was obtained from the session, either from get or create, and that flow file was not transferred anywhere and was not removed, so basically it is unaccounted for. This could not happen from just returning at the beginning in that if statement, so the rest of the processor code is executing and producing this error. You haven't provided the rest of the code so we can't see the problem.

The second issue is fairly self-explanatory. You have a process group under version control, but the registry client that was used to start version control somehow no longer exists. I don't know how you created this scenario because I believe the UI/API won't let you delete a registry client that has active flows under version control, but you should be able to stop version control on the process group.

Comment: **(1)** "The FlowFileHandlingException...we can't see the problem": But I step through the code. After that `return` inside `if`, it goes inside `AbstractProcessor.onTrigger()` and it throws that exception on [this](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/5825e7bc76a7a590a14ad75041b393c92c0ad038/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processor/AbstractProcessor.java#L31) line. **(2)** "It is normal ... at the beginning": I felt `onTrigger()` is called only when there is some flow file. When else it gets called and why?

Comment: [continued from last comment] Also does it means it does not  make sense to run pipeline till input queue of my custom processor gets flow file and then run custom processor to expect that it will hit breakpoint in `onTrigger()` and give me the input flow file inside session? (because that is not what is happening in my debug session, the flow file remains in the queue and inside `onTrigger()`, there is no flow file)

Comment: [continued from last comment] **(3)**"The second issue ...  the process group": I was not able to get this. What is "registry client"? I never explicitly version controlled anything. I have moved template from one machine to other. Is that the reason for this exception.

Comment: If you can show the entire code of your processor I can tell you why you get the FlowFileHandlingException :)  The second issue is likely because the template you imported had saved the registry information, basically the template was created from a process group that was under version control.

Comment: Two scenarios where onTrigger can get no flow files - 1) if your processor is configured with more than 1 concurrent task, then the framework schedules the processor and each tasks tries to get the flow file, but one of them gets it and one doesnt 2) if your processor is annotated with @ TriggerWhenEmpty, it will execute all the time even if no flow files in the queue

Comment: I put the exact code flow when exception occurs in point 1. The rest of the code which is domain specific is not getting executed when exception occurs. So, it returns from `if`, then it executes `session.commit()` inside `Abstract Processor.onTrigger()` (github link in point 1) which throws Exception. Should I do `session.rollback()` instead of just returning from `if`? It seems that I miss basics of nifi. Noon here..

Comment: The place where the exception happens is not the cause of the exception, the cause is somewhere else in your processor code that is not shown

Comment: There is lot of domain specific code. However, its not getting executed at all. Then how it can cause exception? I really do have `if` block at the start of `onTrigger()`. After returning from `onTrigger()` it gets back to that `session.commit()` of `AbstractProcessor` at [github line](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/5825e7bc76a7a590a14ad75041b393c92c0ad038/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processor/AbstractProcessor.java#L31) & then falls into catch block which throws back `FlowFileHandlingException`. So there is barely any custom processor specific code that is getting executed.

Comment: I believe that the rest of the code in onTrigger is actually executing, otherwise you wouldn't be getting FlowFileHandlingException. You should write a unit test using the mock testing framework, it will produce the error and you can debug easier.

Comment: Extremely sorry. I completely forgot to add stacktrace. Added now. As you can see, it is barely executing my custom processor specific code.

Comment: The stacktrace is not really helpful, this is the standard stacktrace for any processor that fails to commit its session. It is failing to commit the session because there are one or more flow files that are unaccounted for in your onTrigger method, which we can't see.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "there are one or more flow files that are unaccounted for ". There are flow files in input queue and inside `onTrigger()`, `session.get()` gives zero flow files. Does this have anything to do with "unaccounted" flow files?

Comment: Whatever code is after the if statement needs to make sure that every flow file retrieved from session.get(5000) is either transferred to a relationship, or removed from the session. If you write a unit test that sends in one flow file it will probably show you the problem.

Comment: I know you believe it is not making it past the if statement, but it is because otherwise there is no way to get FlowFileHandlingException.

Comment: Yeah thats what I believe cause while debugging/stepping through in eclipse, thats whats happening. But I really dont want to believe my eyes & will try out what you are saying. May be will learn something new. Will come back once I am upto something. By that time, if possible, please answer these doubts: (a) "Whatever code is...removed from the session": but how is this possible when session.get() returns no file? Also what is concept behind that makes you assert this statement?

Comment: [continued from last comment] (b) why there is no way to get FlowFileHandlingException if it isnt making past `if`? What is concept that makes you assert this statement? (c) it seems that I miss some concepts here. Can you share link explaining them  (like above concepts: transferring flow files to relationships, how to transfer, if there is any rule to avoid errors while transferring and FlowFileHandlingException)?

Comment: You can read the [Apache NiFi Developer Guide - Exceptions](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#exceptions-within-the-processor) section which will provide more context, but Bryan wrote much of the code related to this, and I concur that the error you are getting about a flowfile not being transferred to a relationship can't occur from the snippet of code you posted, so please post the entire method body even if you feel it's domain-specific and we won't understand it.

Comment: I have just put code on pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/MrW0JiGm). Sorry for providing obfuscated code. Please see if anything fishy can be found in it. Also I have found that I am getting same exception in both cases: **(I)** when there is some flow file and full `onTrigger()` executes (in which case `session.transfer()` is executed for all files) **(II)** When there is no flow file and onTrigger() returns from inside `if` block.

Comment: the pastebin post seems to be private and I can't see it

Comment: sorry again...my bad , now fixed the link and also the code. Yes yoe were correct...there was something...but my noob eyes with poor experience in nifi werent capable enough to spot stupid simple mistake and I am lonely java+nifi developer in team, so having no more eyes here to scrutinize my code.

Comment: I have one file which splits in multiple further in pipeline. I want all those child files processed in same way. To identify those files are child of same file, I was having UpdateAttribute processor which adds timestamp before splitting & inside processor I was doing `session.get().getAttribute()` to access that attribute (which I did not show in original code as I felt it will be harmless, noob eyes ) & again doing `session.get()` before that `if`. So file obtained in 1st `get()` is getting unaccounted. How should I handle such scenario: having same timestamp for all child files in batch.

Comment: How is the split happening? is it a custom processor or one of the standard split processors?

Comment: I have UpdateAttribute processor which adds timestamp and number of records (say n) to flow file. Then I have SplitJson processor which splits input flow file to n flow files. Inside my custom processor I am accessing these attributes to determine which batch current flow file belongs to (based on timestamp) and whether all flow files of this batch have been received before proceeding to next processor.

Comment: The split processors produce a standard set of "fragment" attributes which you can probably use to know if you got all the splits for a given batch, you can read about the attributes in the documentation of one of the split processors, "Writes Attributes" section - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitJson/index.html