# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/nifi/registry/VariableRegistry while running nifi test cases

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am pretty much new to apache nifi. Couple of days back I stuck at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953174/zero-flow-files-in-ontrigger-method-of-abstractprocessor-of-apache-nifi) problem (which involves miss behaving custom nifi processor). Debugging wasnt helping me well. So I decided to explore nifi mock framework (which I should be doing already, but didnt do it :) as suggested in comments on that question.

I am taking help from these links: [1](https://www.nifi.rocks/developing-a-custom-apache-nifi-processor-unit-tests-partI/), [2](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#testing)

What I was trying to do is to send single flow file to custom processor. For that I saved/serialized actual flow file using MergeContent (with FlowFile v3 version)  and PutFile processor as suggested [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/92345/store-a-flow-to-disk-and-then-reserialize-it-to-co.html). Now I am trying to re-read this file through code in my test using GetFile processor as follows:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import org.apache.nifi.util.TestRunners;
import org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GetFile;
import org.apache.nifi.util.MockFlowFile;
import org.apache.nifi.util.TestRunner;

public class MyCustomProcessorTest {

    @Test
    public void testOnTrigger() {
        TestRunner runner = TestRunners.newTestRunner(new GetFile());
        runner.setProperty(GetFile.DIRECTORY, "C:\\Mahesh\\delete\\serialized-flow-files");
        runner.setProperty(GetFile.KEEP_SOURCE_FILE, "true");
        runner.run(1);

        List<MockFlowFile> results = runner.getFlowFilesForRelationship(GetFile.REL_SUCCESS);
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

This is giving me following error:

[image]

Which maven dependency should I include to get this class? Also is my approach fine or there is any more preferable approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double-check if org.apache.nifi:nifi-api: is in the classpath.

If using maven I would run 
"mvn dependency:tree" to check.

Comment: Yess I added it to my dependency. Now getting `java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.nifi.flowfile.FlowFile.getLineageIdentifiers()Ljava/util/Set`

Comment: Can I see your pom file just to do with the nifi dependencies. Looks like there's a dependency version mismatch

Comment: `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
 <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-processor-utils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-mock</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>` 
at the start of your dependencies section in your pom, are duplicated at the end as well. just do a `mvn dependency:tree` to check what are the version used.

Comment: @Mahesa999 Would be good to know what was the actual cause of the problem?

Comment: Yeah will come back to this in some time, promise...was debugging other code whole day, got it fixed now, but damn lot tired... 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192788/discussion-between-ank-and-mahesha999).

Comment: The issue was that parent pom was having dependency on 0.1.0.incubating versions of nifi-api, nifi-processor-utils, nifi-utils, nifi-security-utils, nifi-mock, but nifi-standard-processors is of version 1.5.0. Dont know why earlier developer was sitting on 0.1.0.incubating...